# Smartgwt ListGrid auto generated selection checkbox column freezing

Tags: java, checkbox, smartgwt, listgrid

I am using smartGwt 4.0, ListGrid allows us to add multiple columns with auto generated checkbox selection. I am using below property to get checkboxs for each record in the grid,

listGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);

I have many columns in the ListGrid so it comes with horizontal scrollbar, when i try to scroll to the right side, the selection checkbox column gets scrolled and after verifying mutil column values user has to scroll all the way left to select the record, this is bit annoying, is there a way to freez the checkbox column in ListGrid...?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it using [ListGridField#setFrozen()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridField.html#setFrozen%28java.lang.Boolean%29).

> whether this field should be "frozen" for the purposes of horizontal scrolling.

sample code:

```
listGridField.setFrozen(true);
```

---

--EDIT--

Try with [ListGrid#freezeField()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#freezeField%28java.lang.Integer%29) or other equivalent methods.

For detailed information have a look at [FrozenFields](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/FrozenFields.html)

**If it doesn't work then add your checkbox column instead of using default checkbox  selection appearance and now make it frozen.**

Comment: Checkbox column is added automatically so i do not have handler to that listGridField so i can not add this property to it. Any suggestions on how to get the handle to that list grid field..?

Comment: can you share the code where this check-box column is added? Try with `ListGrid#getFields()` and check the field type and call the `setFrozen()` on it.

Comment: **but I doubt that is it allowed to change the property once fields are set on grid.**

Comment: where/how are you adding checkbox column on list grid?

Comment: If you can't get the reference of the check box column then create your check box column and provide the same behavior.

Comment: Try with `ListGrid#freezeField()`. Have a look at my edited section.

Comment: I tried doing the getField(0) it gives me first column but that is not  the checkbox column. I m using listGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX); to get the checkbox column.

Comment: @Pramod As I told you, why don't you simply add your check-box column that behave in the same way. Its very simple.